# SQL query to get the distinct adr_id for given subj-id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which holds the data in below given format.

```
   SUBJ_ID    |     ADR_ID    |     ROW_DT
--------------------------------------------------- 
200001243385  |  30000001941  | 1999-10-05 09:19:00
200001243385  |  200001849750 | 2000-12-13 22:28:00
200001243385  |  30000001942  | 2001-10-05 09:19:00
200001243385  |  30000001942  | 2000-12-13 22:28:00
```

if I use given query

```
select top 10 subj_id,
              adr_id,
              count(adr_id) 
from db..table_name 
group by subj_id,adr_id 
Having COUNT(adr_id) > 1
```

Then it will return answer in this format.

```
SUBJ_ID       |     ADR_ID     |   count
-----------------------------------------
200001243385  |  30000001942   |     2
```

But I need to know SQL query to get the answer in this format by ignoring subj_id which have duplicate adr_id's.

Required Answer:

```
   SUBJ_ID    |    ADR_ID    |   count
-----------------------------------------
200001243385  | 30000001941  |      1
200001243385  | 200001849750 |      1
```

Can any one help me please?

Comment: Your query has the answer,In having condition instead of '>1' replace '=1' or '<2'.Having COUNT(adr_id) = 1

Comment: Correct Mohan..I didn't notice. thanks.

Comment: Why bother with the count column if they are all 1?

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
select top 10 subj_id, adr_id, count(adr_id) [count]
from db..table_name
group by subj_id, adr_id
Having COUNT(adr_id) = 1
```

---

Test case:

```
WITH table_name AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    ('200001243385','30000001941', '1999-10-05 09:19:00'),
    ('200001243385','200001849750', '2000-12-13 22:28:00'),
    ('200001243385','30000001942', '2001-10-05 09:19:00'),
    ('200001243385','30000001942', '2000-12-13 22:28:00')) T(SUBJ_ID, ADR_ID, ROW_DT)
)
select top 10 subj_id, adr_id, count(adr_id) count
from table_name
group by subj_id, adr_id
Having COUNT(adr_id) = 1
```

**Result:**

```
subj_id      adr_id       count
------------ ------------ -----------
200001243385 200001849750 1
200001243385 30000001941  1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want window functions:

```
select top 10 subj_id, adr_id
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by subj_id, adr_id) as cnt
      from db..table_name t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

I'm not sure why you want a column with "1" in it in the output.  But you can add that in if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your "having" clause to specify the count should equal 1. Or if you would like to combine the queries, remove the having clause altogether:

```
SELECT subj_id, adr_id, count(*)
FROM t
GROUP BY subj_id, adr_id
```

Tested here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc918/3